# How to interact with listview items

Tags: android, listview, listactivity

I'm trying to interact with CheckBox instances in ListView. I made an array of CheckBox, copied CheckBox item in ListView to it, and then made a public method - checkIfNull - to get this array, but it says all the elements in the array are null. Would you please help me to figure this out? Below is my code of ListAtapter that extends BaseAdapte, the main activity and the layout of my listview.

Thank you in advance

```
<TableLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1" />
    <TwoLineListItem android:id="@+id/twoLineListItem1" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingTop="10px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" 
                android:text="TextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/textView2" 
                android:text="TextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" 
                android:paddingTop="30px"/>
    </TwoLineListItem>
    <TextView android:text="TextView" 
        android:id="@+id/textView3" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10px"/>
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radioButton1" 
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

public class ListViewSampleMain extends ListActivity {
    private String[] list1 = {"Lionel Messi", "Kai Hansen", "Jim Carrey","Christoper Nolan",
            "ABC", "Persona", "Shawdow and Collosuss"};
    private String[] list2 = {"Argentina", "Germany", "Canada", "U.S.A.", 
            "Unknown", "Japan", "Ico"};
    private String[] list3 = {"March 2nd", "January 22th", "December 15th", "Februray 1st",
            "May 4th", "August 23th", "July 17th"};

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    createListViewWithListActivity();        
}

private void createListViewWithListActivity(){
    ListAdapter listAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, list1, list2, list3);
    this.setListAdapter(listAdapter);
    listAdapter.checkIfNull();
}
```

---

public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private String[] list1;
    private String[] list2;
    private String[] list3;
    private static LayoutInflater layoutInflater = null;
    private CheckBox[] cb_list;

`public ListAdapter(Context context, 
        String[] list1, String[] list2, String[] list3){
    this.mContext = context;
    this.list1 = list1;
    this.list2 = list2;
    this.list3 = list3;
    ListAdapter.layoutInflater =
        (LayoutInflater)this.mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    cb_list = new CheckBox[list1.length];
}

public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list1.length;
}

public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arg0;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    // To interact with OnClickListener()
    final int pos = position;

    if(convertView == null){ // check if convertView exists
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_layout, null);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.tv1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        viewHolder.tv2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        viewHolder.tv3 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        viewHolder.cb = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

        viewHolder.cb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "You clicked: "+pos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        cb_list[position] = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
    }
    viewHolder.tv1.setText(this.list1[position]);
    viewHolder.tv2.setText(this.list2[position]);
    viewHolder.tv3.setText(this.list3[position]);

    return view;
}

public void checkIfNull(){
    for(int i=0; i<cb_list.length; i++){
        if (cb_list[i] == null)
            Log.d("checkIfNull method", "cb_list["+i+"] is null");
        else if (cb_list[i] != null)
            Log.d("checkIfNull method", "cb_list["+i+"] is not null");
    }
}

public static class ViewHolder{
    public TextView tv1;
    public TextView tv2;
    public TextView tv3;
    public CheckBox cb;
}`

}

Comment: I'm pretty sure the checkIfNull() method will execute before your List item views are rendered, which is why the checkboxes in the array are null. Add log messages inside the getView and checkIfNull, and see which one executes before.

Comment: Thanks dmon. I figured out that the getview() method is invoked after the screen displays all the list;which means the invocation may begin the launch. Would you help to find out the other way to interact with the CheckBox array?

Comment: The right way to do it would be to have a boolean array that holds what is stored in the checkboxes. Then have each checkboxes onclick method update that array accordingly. You don't need to keep an array of Checkboxes just to save a boolean state.

Comment: Thank you dmon! That was a good advice!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you checking the checkboxes for null? You would check if the checkbox is "true" checked or "false" unchecked.

Comment: I want make a method related to checkboxes in the main method. However, I can't get checkboxes because the log says they are null when I call them in the main method.

Comment: could you post your layout for the listview?